# Is it possible to share internet connection via remote desktop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-update

At work I have two computers connected to the same network, each user can download a limited quota of 400 MB each day from internet, but I need more than this. There is a server computer beside me which has unlimited internet access, and I can connect to this computer via remote desktop. Is it possible to use server computer's internet to upgrade my windows 7 to 10 though remote desktop? Not to mention, automatic updates are closed by administrator.

Comment: I think there is no possibility for this.

Comment: Are you trying to bypass your company's policies?

Comment: Your company set these restrictions up for a reason (good or bad).  Bypassing them without permission will probably get you in to a lot of trouble.

Comment: Ask your admin to extend your quota? After all, you have good reasons to use so much bandwidth, don't you?

Comment: I seriously doubt your company will appreciate you using a server for internet browsing... and seriously, for a work computer, 400MB per day is a *lot* of bandwidth. Unless you're downloading all kinds of things, there should be no need for more. Tread carefully before you continue down this path, if you're doing something you're not supposed to, it will land you in trouble.

Comment: And no, if you don't have administrator access on your computer, you will not be able to upgrade to windows 10. Seriously, your IT Dept clearly doesn't want you upgrading your computer, why else is there a 400mb limit per day and auto updates are disabled and you don't have admin access? Continuing down this path is nothing but bad for you.

Comment: I can download everything by using server's internet, and I don't want to bypass company's policies! I have downloaded a file and when I execute that file it starts to download windows update files, but it reaches the quota  and it stops.

Comment: Overall, it was a question for me, if I can access to internet through RDP or not? Yes, the better way would be to ask network administrator to upgrade it for me. But, I'll try VPN approach as well ;)

Comment: @Patzu You cannot install windows updates without administrator permissions. What you are doing is futile. Besides, your IT department would have upgraded your PC to Windows 10 if they wanted you to use Windows 10. It's their computer, not yours. Don't forget that. Continuing down this path is almost guaranteed to be in violation of your company's IT policies. Go talk with IT, get their permission and blessing before you continue. If they say No, then that's the end of the road.

Comment: @Patzu Installing VPN or Proxy software on a company server is very likely to get you fired. It would at most companies. It's a massive security risk, and is a clear circumvention of IT policy.

Comment: As a Network Administrator myself I can promise you with absolutely no doubt, just for what you have already done you would be on gardening leave 15 minutes after I found out and for what you're trying to do you'd be fired by the end of the day. You sound like a school child trying to bypass their web filter the way you're talking, except now you're in the real world and a bad reference will affect the rest of your life. It is absolutely not worth it.

Comment: Yea, I'm going to echo most of the others here: As one responsible for making sure computers are running smoothly for employees of an org, I make the decisions when and whether to upgrade, and I put policies in place to make sure those computers behave in a predictable way for the staff so that they are maximally effective within the constraints of their job and corporate policy. Users going McGyver and trying to get around rules and policies WILL be reprimanded and possibly let go. What you're doing: You'd be fired.

Comment: "each user can download a limited quota of 400 MB each day from internet" Does that include regular HTTP traffic?

Comment: @Ashigore "For what you have already done" being RDPing into an unsecured server? - Without further proof of malice on his side, he would get told off at my company and you'd get fired by the end of the day for not securing the server! - I agree with you on the rest of your comment, though.

Comment: The "most harmless" thing that can happen to you is your IT people refusing to support the machine that you unilaterally decided to upgrade if there are any problems - "you tampered with it, YOU are now responsible for making it work."

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek It's not an unsecured server. OP has RDP access to it for his job. OP is abusing that access, and has plans to grossly abuse that access, which is where he would face disciplinary action or termination.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about circumventing network security/policies at an institution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

RDP is not capable of Internet sharing, so you can't share Internet using RDP with standard applications. There are many way to share Internet from a Windows box to another one. I suggest you to use VPN. You should do following steps:

1. Run VPN Server on your server with unlimited internet access
2. Connect to VPN server from your limited computer

Comment: A simple proxy server is even easier, and gets you access to web browsing at least.

Comment: I dont know any **build-in** proxy server in MS-Windows. So you need to install a third-party application on MS-Windows to make it a proxy server. But any MS-Windows has a simple built-in VPN server. Also every traffic can pass through VPN but some proxies are limited to HTTP or TCP-based protocols.

Comment: Sure, VPN is available but it's a far cry from simple... at least when compared to something like the AnalogX proxy.  http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/proxy/Freeware.htm  If only basic web browsing is needed, that's probably much easier and will require no extra permissions.

Comment: I'm not sure that upgrading win 7 to win 10 can be done by a simple proxy or need whole system internet access. So if it can, the proxy server is acceptable answer, else you need solution like VPN.

Comment: It can.  A proxy is still a common way for internet access.  Microsoft just uses their CDN and HTTPS for distributing Windows upgrades.

Answer (score 6):

1. Install [Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) on your server.
2. Use [MyEnTunnel](http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/MyEnTunnel) to make a
   SOCKS server on your computer. MyEnTunnel uses SSH to pass SOCKS
   request to the SSH server.
3. Use [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/)  to redirect any applications traffic to the SOCKS sever created by MyEnTunnel. This step is not required if the update program accept SOCKS.

Comment: 4. Update your CV.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You might wanna make that step 0.

Answer (score 5):

You could try upgrading your PC using DVD or USB media instead of an online install. If you can't obtain the DVD elsewhere you could still download the media image using the server and then transfer it to a local PC that has a DVD burner (possibly using Remote Desktop's drive sharing but using a shared folder on the network would be better).

Comment: Once you download the DVD image, there's no reason to actually put it onto an actual DVD.

Comment: @BenVoigt Personally I think it makes installing on multiple PCs more convenient. You can also use it for recovery or clean reinstallation if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you have administrative access to the server, you might be able to set it up as a proxy server, then connect your two computers to the internet through this proxy server, and run your upgrades. This doesn't involve any remote desktop though.

In theory you could write code that abuses the RDP protocol to tunnel internet traffic, but it's unlikely a tool like that already exists...

Comment: Yes I have access as an administrator to the server, but not to my own computer as an admin. Should I search, How to create a proxy server in windows?

Comment: I'm not familiar with setting it up myself, but I'm pretty sure it's a valid solution...

Comment: No need for admin access even.

Answer (score 0):

If you only care about the Win 10 update, the easiest way would be to download an ISO version, configure a shared folder on your Win 7 PC, and place the ISO there from a remote desktop session on your server.

If you actually want to get better access to internet in general, then the easiest way could be to execute a proxy server app on a remote desktop session, like CCProxy or [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/Download/), note that depending on the configuration of the firewall on the server, running such an app (or any similar app that opens a port on the system) may ask you for elevated privileges.

The proxy app will have to be configured for a specific port, you will then need to configure that port + the ip address of your server as a proxy in the browser of your laptop.

Good luck.